# Did Boba Fett's armour use durasteel or beskar?

Tags: star-wars, boba-fett

**Did Boba Fett's armour use durasteel or beskar?**

Wookieepedia is vague.

Boba armour has no durasteel or beskar in ***Canon***. For ***Legends***, Boba Fett is also vague; however, it was passed down to Jango.

In ***Canon*** Jango did not use beskar armour:

> However, (Jango) Fett's armor itself was fashioned from durasteel alloy, while most Mandalorian armor was made from beskar.

In ***Legends***

> (Jango) Fett wore Mandalorian armor in the "shocktrooper" style common during his time, although instead of the more traditional beskar plating, he utilized the less resilient and less expensive durasteel alloy for his armor. (https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jango_Fett/Legends)

However, The Clone Wars (T.V), Boba does not start wearing Jango's armour and the first time we get to see was in *The Empire Strikes Back* (ESB). I assume Boba kept wearing his armour for *Return of the Jedi* when he fell into the sarlacc.

> *The Mandalorian* (Mando): Eventually,  Boba Fett gets his armour and helmet; however, it is unclear whether it is **beskar** or **durasteel**.

I found this website which discusses the material it is made of: https://www.slashgear.com/mandalorian-s2e6-lets-talk-about-boba-fetts-armor-04649828/

Comment: Where did your quote about Jango's armor in Canon come from?  I don't recall it being mentioned in any of the canon material i've read or watched.

Comment: I think Beskar is a new addition to the lore, it started in a n article in SW Insider and it is clearer by the episode that The Mandalorian is trying to glue old EU (like Thrawn) and new canon in an elegant way.

Comment: If Boba's helmet is Beskar, then, why the dent (from his duel with Cad Bane) on it?

Comment: @BingoMehndra I like the Cad Bane v.s. Boba Fett; however, is that **Canon**?

Comment: @psubsee2003 For a few weeks, I started working on this. Apparently, Jango Fett Wookieepedia (Canon) has been removed. Now, I cannot find: "beskar" or "durasteel" and they added the stuff from *Mando*.

Comment: The 'Ultimate Star Wars' factbook says that Jango's armour is both "energised durasteel" *and* "advanced Mandalorian armor...".

Comment: The same book also makes it clear that Mandalorian armour does employ beskar steel so it's possible that Jango's is an older form (or just cheaper).

Comment: @psubsee2003 - See above. Ultimate Star Wars is a canon factbook

Comment: I edited my answer, you should find that it is much more satisfactory

Comment: We have proof-positive from [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Absolutely-Everything-Expanded/dp/1465455639) that Boba's suit of armour isn't the same as Jango's. At best it contains *pieces* of his father's suit; https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQV8J.jpg. This would explain how Jango's suit could be made of durasteel and Boba's could be made of beskar.

Comment: Beskar. _It’s the best-kar!_ ™

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok first off before we begin.

Jango Fett **did** have beskar in his armor in the canon.

> As revealed in the latest episode of the Mandalorian Boba Fett wore Jango's old beskar armor. And that Jango was a Mandalorian by creed, and so he wore Mandolorian armor which is: made with Beskar

And in the Mandalorian Din acquires Boba Fett's armor because it had beskar. If it were just durasteel, then Din wouldn't have cared about it at all.

Boba Fett wears **Mandalorian** armor per my evidence suggests. **Mandalorian armor** is made with **beskar**, and that means it's made with beskar. To add even more to it, durasteel may be strong, but not "deflect blaster bolts without them leaving a scratch" strong. Boba Fett's armor literally **can not** be *just* durasteel, it *has* to have beskar

Wookieepedia agrees with me:

> Beskar could protect the wearer from blasters and even lightsabers.
> The bounty hunter Jango and his cloned son, Boba Fett wore customized
> Mandalorian armor, which was made with beskar.

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandalorian_armor

The final conclusion from all the admittedly conflicting sources is that Jango and Boba's armor was a **mix** of durasteel and beskar.

Because multiple different legit sources say two different things. But the notice the wording in the Wookieepedia quote

> Jango and his cloned son, Boba Fett wore customized Mandalorian armor, which was made *with* beskar.

So the conclusion is that Boba and Jango used an alloy of Beskar *and* durasteel.
So your answer is both.

Comment: I'm not so sure Din only cared about beskar. Din seems to care if you're merely *dressed* as a Mandalorian. Remember, it's his religion.

Comment: yes but also the Jawas acted as if it were extremely valuable, valuable enough to pay for with a very rare crystal, which as we know, durasteel is very cheap, so it must have been beskar

Comment: Maybe, but it did feature armor of some sort and came with a functional rocket pack and missile launcher. Pretty valuable, even if it's not beskar. Plus you can pretend to be Boba Fett. I mean that last point is [a major selling point in the real world](https://www.officialstarwarscostumes.com/boba-fett-costumes)

Comment: My issue is the same. You're basing this on an assumption rather than evidence. You're probably not wrong, but you could also be not right.

Comment: Again, Boba Fett wears **Mandolorian** armor per my evidence suggests. **Mandolorian** armor is **made out of beskar**. Logic, not an assumption. Add on the fact that the Jawa's asked for so much for Boba's armor, which Jawa's should know whether or not a suit of armor is beskar or durasteel, and that means it's beskar. To add even more to it, durasteel may be strong, but not "deflect blaster bolts without them leaving a scratch" strong. Boba Fett's armor literally can not be durasteel, it has to be beskar

Comment: He certainly wear mandalorian-*style* armour. The fact that it's shaped much the same doesn't speak to its material.

Comment: no, he wears Jango's armor, Jango was a Mandolorian and raised by a Mandolorian, so he was Mandolorian, so he wears, Mandolorian armor. How is this hard to understand?

Comment: One does not simply wear Mandolorian-style armor if your Mandolorian, one wears the real thing.

Comment: The episode where Boba recovers his armor very clearly spells out that Boba Fett's armor is Mandalorian Armor, not merely in the style of it. There is simply no room left for doubt. And if you did still doubt anyway, you can even decipher the holographic writing he shows for further information on the armor's heritage, which links it to Jaster Mereel, a previously legends-only Mandalorian character.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that the mando himself didn't have beskar the first time we saw him. It's not unreasonable to think that Jango's armor isn't guaranteed to be beskar either. We need something more convincing than its style, I think.

Comment: @MatthewGreen he certainly had some beskar, but not enough for a full set of armor.

Comment: @MatthewGreen Din most definitely had beskar, he just had a less pure form of it, that is why the mudhorn destroyed his breastplate

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Legends. Do you use different spellings (Mandalorian/Mandolorian) intentionally? If yes, then what's the difference?

Comment: @defaultlocale no the misspelling was not intentional, I just keep misspelling it

Comment: The *Ultimate Star Wars* factbook explicitly states that Jango's armour was durasteel

Comment: @Valorum then post that as an answer, then let the OP pick which answer they accept

Comment: The Book of Boba Fett now directly claims that Boba's armor is beskar (ep 4).

Comment: Yes I saw that, and I literally thought of this post I made.

Answer (score 14):

According to the 2019 reference book *Ultimate Star Wars*, in canon, Boba's armor was made from durasteel.

> Conforming to almost exact specifications of traditional Mandalorian garb, Boba Fett's armor is made of durasteel rather than the customary beskar steel, and has been heavily modified.
>
> *Ultimate Star Wars (2019)*, page 279, section Boba Fett's Armor

However, in Episode 4 of *The Book of Boba Fett*, Boba refers to it as **beskar** to Fennec Shand. As the more recent source (2022), this takes precedence.

Comment: What happened to Pablo Hidalgo keeping the canon consistent?

Comment: @Adamant As he describes it, his role as "Lore Advisor" is to suggest worldbuilding elements from existing lore (usually Legends material) that the writers of movie/TV Star Wars productions can build on or draw from [if they choose](https://twitter.com/pabl0hidalgo/status/1532497488560525312). This was likely brought up at some point during the making of BoBF, but I'd guess the writers felt it would be a clearer or better story decision to stick to what the audience knows about Mandalorian armor from _The Mandalorian_.